# Rectangle and circle overlap

Tags: geometry

> As shown below, ABCD is a rectangle with AE=3, AD=4, DF=5. AB passes through the center, O. Find the diameter of the circle
>
> https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/s8dspavf

I can find that DEF is isoceles with DF=DE=5. I really have no idea how to proceed on finding the radius. Thanks!

Comment: Draw a perpendicular from E to DF (new point K). Notice EK=AD and DF=AE+KF. Next, some trigonometrics.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be the point making $DEGF$ a rhombus, it is constructed by making $DEGF$ a parallelogram. So $G$ is on the parallel through $E$ to $DF$. It also fulfills $GE=GF$, so it is $O$.

Answer (score 1):

Find the angle of (angle)OEF

because this is a circle |EO|=|FO|

This Means (angle)OEF = (angle)OFE

calculate the slope using the angle = (2/3) v -(2/3)

|AD|/(2(2/3))=3

The radius is 3